Stress-Energy Tensor and Variation of Action in CFT
I'm reading the CFT chapter of String Theory by David Tong, he wrote the variation of the action to argue how to write the stress-energy tensor in CFT,
\begin{equation}
\delta S = \int d^2 \sigma j^\mu \partial_\mu \epsilon
\end{equation}
I don't understand how this came about, eventually I consulted 1511.04074 where he wrote the stress-energy tensor in eq.(2.58) and the variation of the action in eq.(2.64),
\begin{equation}
j^\mu_a = \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \partial_\nu \phi - \mathcal{L} \delta^\mu_\nu \right) \frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta \epsilon_a} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\delta S = -\int d^d x j^\mu_a \partial_\mu \epsilon_a
\end{equation}
He relegated the derivation as an exercise in chapter 9 which contains all the exercises, specifically, exercise 10.
$$x'^\mu = x^\mu + \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_a}, \qquad \phi'(x') = F(\phi(x)) = \phi(x) + \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a}$$
$F(\phi(x))$ or $\phi'(x')$ is just the transformation that is a function of $\phi$.
$$\frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x^\nu} = \delta^\mu_\nu + \partial_\nu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right), \qquad \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu} = \delta^\nu_\mu - \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right)$$
\begin{equation}
S = \int d^dx \mathcal{L}(\phi, \partial_\mu \phi)
\end{equation}
We want to compute $\delta S = S' - S$ up to first order in $\epsilon$.
\begin{align}
S' & = \int d^d x' \mathcal{L} (\phi', \partial'_\mu \phi')\\
& = \int d^dx \Bigg|\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \Bigg| \mathcal{L} \left(F(\phi(x)), \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu} \partial_\nu F(\phi(x)) \right)\\
& = \int d^dx \left( 1 + \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) \right) \mathcal{L} \left(\phi(x) + \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a}, \left(\delta^\nu_\mu - \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) \right) \left(\partial_\nu \phi + \partial_\nu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) \right) \right)\\
& = \int d^dx \left( 1 + \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) \right) \mathcal{L} \left(\phi(x) + \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a}, \partial_\mu \phi + \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) - \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) \partial_\nu \phi \right)\\
& = \int d^dx \left( 1 + \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) \right) \left[ \mathcal{L}(\phi, \partial_\mu \phi ) + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi} \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a} + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) \partial_\nu \phi \right]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
S'-S & = \int d^dx \left[ \mathcal{L} \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi} \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a} + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) \partial_\nu \phi  \right]\\
& = \int d^dx \left[ \mathcal{L} \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi} \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a} - \partial_\mu \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)}  \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a} + \partial_\mu \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)}  \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a}\right) - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) \partial_\nu \phi  \right]\\
& = \int d^dx \left[ \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi} - \partial_\mu \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \right) \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a} + \mathcal{L} \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) + \partial_\mu \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)}  \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a}\right) - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) \partial_\nu \phi  \right]\\
\end{align}
In the first line, we replaced the third term through a total derivative,
\begin{equation}
\partial_\mu \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)}  \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a}\right) = \partial_\mu \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)}  \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a} + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right)
\end{equation}
In the last line, the first term is just the Euler-Lagrange equation.
Thus,
\begin{align}
S'-S & = \int d^dx \left[ \mathcal{L} \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \right) \partial_\nu \phi + \partial_\mu \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)}  \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a}\right) \right]\\
& = \int d^dx \left[ \mathcal{L} \delta^\mu_\nu \frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \partial_\mu \epsilon_a - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \partial_\nu \phi \frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \partial_\mu \epsilon_a + \partial_\mu \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)}  \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a}\right) \right]\\
& = - \int d^dx \left[ \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \partial_\nu \phi - \mathcal{L} \delta^\mu_\nu \right) \frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta \epsilon_a} \partial_\mu \epsilon_a - \partial_\mu \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)}  \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a}\right) \right]
\end{align}
However, I'm stuck in the last line. The first term is already a term in $j^\mu_a$. I'm not sure how to resolve the total derivative term. Any help?
